# In BigQuery, can I add rows of missing data?

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

I have a table where each row represents the number of transactions a user has per day. If they had no transaction that day then they don't have a row for that date. How can I add these 'missing rows' and set the number of transactions to 0

My table:

```
Date       | User | numTransactions
2020-01-01 | anna | 2
2020-01-01 | john | 3
2020-01-02 | anna | 1
2020-01-04 | anna | 1
2020-01-05 | john | 2
```

Anna had transactions on Jan 1,2, and 4 but not Jan 3, and 5

John had transactions on Jan 1, and 5 but not Jan 2, 3, and 4

I want to add rows which shows the dates there are 0 transactions

```
Date       | User | numTransactions
2020-01-01 | anna | 2
2020-01-01 | john | 3
2020-01-02 | anna | 1
2020-01-04 | anna | 1
2020-01-05 | john | 2
2020-01-02 | john | 0
2020-01-03 | anna | 0
2020-01-03 | john | 0
2020-01-04 | john | 0
2020-01-05 | anna | 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join with [GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#generate_date_array):

```
WITH test_table AS (
  SELECT DATE '2020-01-01' AS Date, 'anna' AS User, 2 AS numTransactions UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-01-01', 'john', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-01-02', 'anna', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-01-04', 'anna', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-01-05', 'john', 2
),
clients_list AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT User FROM test_table
)
SELECT 
  Date,
  User,
  IFNULL(numTransactions, 0) AS numTransactions
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-01-01', '2020-01-05')) AS Date 
CROSS JOIN clients_list
LEFT JOIN test_table USING(Date, User)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend writing the code in this fashion:

```
WITH t AS (
      SELECT DATE '2020-01-01' AS Date, 'anna' AS User, 2 AS numTransactions UNION ALL
      SELECT '2020-01-01', 'john', 3 UNION ALL
      SELECT '2020-01-02', 'anna', 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT '2020-01-04', 'anna', 1 UNION ALL
      SELECT '2020-01-05', 'john', 2
     )
SELECT u.user, COALESCE(dte, u.date) as date, 
       (CASE WHEN dte = u.date THEN u.numTransactions ELSE 0 END) as numTransactions
FROM (SELECT user, date, numTransactions,
             COALESCE(DATE_ADD(LEAD(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY date), INTERVAL -1 DAY), DATE '2020-01-05') as end_date
      FROM t
     ) u LEFT JOIN
     UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(date, end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) dte
     ON 1=1
ORDER BY user, date;
```

This is slightly simpler than generating all the dates up-front (not requiring getting the unique names and then re-joining to the same table).

Much more important are the performance characteristics, which have proven very important in my experience in making this scalable.  Basically, the `CROSS JOIN` for generating all user/date combinations uses a lot of resources.  This version keeps all the operations "local" to a given user (well, there is some data movement to get all the users co-located on the same node).

Specifically, I have seen queries that run out of resources or literally take hours to complete using the `CROSS JOIN` method finish within a minute using this method.